# Managed loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In simplest case, I get infinite loop that works in separated thread:

```
while True:
   # Do
```

Sometimes I need to stop this loop by condition for some period of time. Then to start again.
This mechanism should work automatically.

Which approaches are exist for that?

Comment: inside loop use variables like `paused = False` to control it.

Comment: Place a lock at the beginning of the loop. Simply acquire and release the lock. To stop the loop, acquire the lock from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to run the while loop on a different thread and have it keep track of the variable on the main thread. However it is necessary to kill the while thread when you wish to end the program.

```
import time
import winsound
import threading

class Player():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Shared Variable.
        self.alarm_status = True
        self.thread_kill = False

    def start_sound(self):
        while True and not self.thread_kill:
            # Do somthing only if flag is true
            if self.alarm_status == True:
                winsound.PlaySound("alarm.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)


    def stop_sound(self):
        # Update the variable to stop the sound
        self.alarm_status = False

    #Function to run your start_alarm on a different thread
    def start_thread(self):
        #Set Alarm_Status to true so that the thread plays the sound
        self.alarm_status = True
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.start_sound)
        t1.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            user_in = str(raw_input('q: to quit,p: to play,s: to Stop\n'))
            if user_in == "q":
                #Signal the thread to end. Else we ll be stuck in for infinite time.
                self.thread_kill = True
                break
            elif user_in == "p":
                self.start_thread()
            elif user_in == "s":
                self.stop_sound()
            else:
                print("Incorrect Key")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Player().run()
```